# Why does mysql not let connect through domain name but lets use localhost?

Tags: php, mysql

As far as I know, https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php uses `$hostame`. I have bought a server and domain name from hostinger. The domain name is `sandygardening.com`. `$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "DB_USER_NAME", "DB_PASSWORD", "DB_NAME");` works perfect. But if I put the actual hostname as:

```
$conn = new mysqli("sandygardening.com", DB_USER_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, "DB_NAME");
```

This doesn't work at all, gives me access denied for user...

The exact errors are as following:

With `$conn = new mysqli("https://sandygardening.com/", DB_USER_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/DB_USER_NAME/domains/sandygardening.com/public_html/crimewiki/include/functions.php on line 4  
Notice: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/DB_USER_NAME/domains/sandygardening.com/public_html/crimewiki/include/functions.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/DB_USER_NAME/domains/sandygardening.com/public_html/crimewiki/include/functions.php(4): mysqli->__construct('https://sandyga...', 'DB_USER_NAME', 'password', 'DB_NAME') #1
```

Then with `$conn = new mysqli("sandygardening.com", DB_USER_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, "DB_NAME");`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'DB_USER_NAME'@'2a02:4780:3:5::c' (using password: YES) in /home/DB_USER_NAME/domains/sandygardening.com/public_html/crimewiki/include/functions.php:4 Stack trace: #0
```

The later error also appears if I use the ip address as host name as well.

I have a shared hosting. All these commands are run on the server in a php file. I don't have access to server's htaccess, php.ini or httd.conf etc files. My question is what causes mysql to only listen to `localhost` and not to the actual `hostname`? And is it usually this way for most servers?

Comment: Did you check if the MySQL user has the correct rights to be accessed from other hosts? User can be bound to localhost only, so any other access would be denied.

Comment: Not domain but host name in this domain must be used.

Comment: PLease [edit] your question to show the error message you received.

Comment: @KhorneHoly Hostinger shows me _List of Current MySQL Databases And Users_ then _MySQL Host: localhost_. I think it is bound to only localhost as you say.  My question is, isn't `host` supposed to same for `mysql` and php? In my knowledge `host` means the server-name/ip-address. Why whould the hosting provider not allow actual host as hostName?

Comment: @Akina I don't know the difference in hostname and domain name. I have only `sandygardening.com` and its ip address `109.106.254.113` which both I think is the hostname .

Comment: @O.Jones please see the edit.

Comment: "Access denied for user" is pretty clear. What have you tried to resolve that problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I continued with `localhost` in my production code as I could not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- First error message: **[getaddrinfo failed](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)** when doing `$conn = new mysqli("https://sandygardening.com/", ...)`;

  This is because `new mysqli()` expects a [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) like `example.com` in its first parameter, but you gave it a [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) like `https://example.com/`. When it looked up that URL as if it were a hostname, it gacked. You fixed that problem in your second attempt.
- Second error message: **Access denied for user 'someuser'@'someIPv6Addr' (using password: YES)**

  This means your php software was able to get to your MySQL server, but the server rejected your username/host/password combination. Unlike many systems, MySQL checks the host machine you connect from as well as your username and password. Your existing user account probably is for `'someuser'@'localhost'` which allows connections via `localhost` only. You'll need to add another user, `'someuser'@'%'`. That user will be able to connect from any host on the network. (Security issue? yes indeed.)

  Ask your hosting vendor how to add that user to MySQL.

> My question is what causes mysql to only listen to localhost and not to the actual hostname?

Some MySQL servers are configured only to listen on the localhost (aka `127.0.0.1`, aka `::1`, aka loopback, network interface. (Those servers actually listen for a local socket connection, but that's a long story.) It's a security measure. But your MySQL server is, in fact, listening for connections from the network. We know because it got as far as checking your username.

This stuff is confusing, especially for beginners. That's why budget hosting vendors try to give very clear instructions, but don't explain how to do things in multiple different ways.